# Is it possible to get array length inline

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I have to access `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` value by key (that I get from array I'm creating inline) like so:

```
var someString = "1.2.3";
someDictionary[someString.Split('.').ToArray()[ /---> self.Length <---/ - 1 ]];
```

**Question:** Is it possible to get array Length inline without creating new variable and assigning array to it?

Comment: Don't have an answer for you but .Split() already gives an array...

Comment: Yeah, and how do you get array length? @EpicKip

Comment: @PavelSanatov what is the goal of your code? Why do you need the length of the array? Can you describe by words what you are doing with someString and someDictionary here?

Comment: How would I get length in my example `someString.Split('.').ToArray()[ /---> self.Length <---/ - 1 ]` ?

Comment: @BradleyUffner how is that inline... he wants it when creating the array and use the value in creation (not possible)

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I didn't see the `-1` hiding in there.  I thought he just wanted the length.

Comment: Okay, so using Linq is much easier-to-read solution for this problem.

Comment: Who went and checked IL/source code to see if ToArray is optimized for when someone calls it with an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this. You need to store intermediate value in a variable if you want to access it twice.
I see no sense in trying to do this without additional variable - at least, your approach is absolutely unreadable.

However, as I understand, by `[self.Length - 1]` you want to access the last value in this array.

If yes, then you can just use [LINQ `.Last`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var someString = "1.2.3";
someDictionary[someString.Split('.').Last()]; // someDictionary["3"]
```